# How to select categories within data using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a beginner with D3 and any help would be much appreciated.

In this chart, a circle is generated for each entry for the category "wins." So, in this case, there are 4 circles generated with a different radius.

I would like to return data for "wins," but only for the categories "Best Picture." In this case, only 2 circles would be generated. Is this possible to do by adding to the function --  .attr('r', function(d) {return radiusScale(d.wins);}) and if so, what should I change?

```
var data = [
        {decade: '1920s', category: 'Best Picture', wins: 2, nominations: 3},
        {decade: '1920s', category: 'Best Director', wins: 1, nominations: 9},
        {decade: '1930s', category: 'Best Picture', wins: 3, nominations: 6},
        {decade: '1930s', category: 'Best Director', wins: 1, nominations: 7},

];

var radiusScale = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([0, 40]).range([0, 40]);



d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', function(d) {return radiusScale(d.wins);})
    .attr('cx', function(d, i) {return i * 80 + 50;})
    .attr('cy', 50);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to get only the data elements you want:

```
d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(data.filter(function(d) { return d.category == "Best Picture"; }))
  .enter()
  ...
```